# How to avoid to do not close dropdown menu onclick link inside it?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, navbar

I am using one online bootstrap theme for my project.
Below is my menu bar with links inside it.

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
    <div class="menu_section">
      <h3>Dashboard</h3>       
        <ul class="nav side-menu">
          <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-table"></i>Home</a></li>  
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Society Profile <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">                      
              <li><a href="society_profile.php">General Profile</a></li>          
              <li><a href="index2.php">Members Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="index1.php">Units Profile</a></li>    
              <li><a href="charges.php">Charge Master</a></li>   
              <li><a href="under_construction1.php">Interest Setup</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction2.php">Billing Templates</a></li>
              <li><a href="chartsOfaccounts.php">Chart of Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction3.php">Vendors Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>                  
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> Account transactions<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
              <li><a href="bill.php">Generate Bill/Debit Note</a></li>
              <li><a href="receipt.php">Receipt/Credit Note</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction4.php">Expenses</a></li>
              <li><a href="payment.php">Payments</a></li>
              <li><a href="journal.php">Journal</a></li>
              <li><a href="transfer.php">Transfer</a></li>   
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i>Office Management<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
              <li><a href="under_construction5.php">Notice Board Post</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction6.php">Members Applications</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction7.php">Opinion Polling</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction8.php">Elections for Committee</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction9.php">Register of members</a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction10.php">Transfer Register</a></li>       
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Member's Section <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">                      
              <li><a href="home1.php">DashBoard </a></li>
              <li><a href="index11.php"> Members </a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction11.php"> Vendors </a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction12.php"> Notice Board </a></li>
              <li><a href="under_construction13.php">Applications to Society </span></a></li>              
            </ul>                    
          </li>                                     
        </ul>
    </div>       
</div>
```

> My problem is when i click one of the links inside main menu: for e.g:
>   If i click on **General Profile** inside of ***society profile***  Onclick
>   link whole **society porfile** menu gets closed once and open immediately.
>   It looks so irritating to see that. I want solution for this close and
>   open whole menu. If i click on any link inside menu the menu should be
>   remains open. it should not be closed once and then open. sorry for my
>   bad english. i hope you get my problem.

Comment: you realize you are redirecting to society_profile.php when you click  General Profile ?

Comment: i can able to get society_profile.php on click general profile. and i dont get you bro sorry

Comment: your page redirects when you click a link man

Comment: you lose the state of the menu

Comment: yup bro it redirects on given link

Comment: so you lose the open state of your menu

Comment: bro solution on this issue?

Comment: don't use links :))

Comment: ya its get closed on click any link and immediately opens. but i dont want to get closed it

Comment: i tried with removing links and it remains same.. not working

Comment: you removed the links and the page still redirected?

Comment: obvious bro i used anchor tag. so if i remove link or not page will always redirected to given link

Comment: so the page still redirects even after you removed the link tag

Comment: yup. do you have any solution or not?

Comment: your code doesn't indicate  how the page still redirects, do you have any javascript events binded to this menu?

Comment: yup as i mentioned i used online bootstrap theme. and that jquery code is so huge so i cant able to get wts the solution for this.

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle?